# MongoDB Meteor Sort only working in Console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have got a meteor application where users can save logs to a database.
Now I want to display them and give the user the option to sort them. All filter like a keyword to search for are working but not the sort algorithm.
The exact problem is that I want to sort only by date (at the moment) but when I change the sort from -1 to 1 nothing changes.
I have got a template helper which returns the logs simply.

It calls:

```
Logs.find({}, {sort:{date: -1}}).fetch;
```

after this call I log the result first and
then I run some other tasks to prepare the data but that has got nothing to do with the output.
I log the exact calls and the results to the console but -1 and 1 have got the same result but if I copy the command and enter it manually in the console the result returns the correct sorted logs.
Here an image of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWKWU.png

I tested the sort in mongodb using meteor mongo manually and there everything works fine. The date is formatted correctly as ISO Date.
I cannot figure out why the result is always the same. On the image the both first two commands an results are made from meteor and the last one is made manually. You should see the difference.

Comment: Adding a dollar sign to your sort might solve the problem: `$sort` instead of just `sort`

Comment: fetch(). No dollar sign for sort in meteor.

Comment: The dollar sign did not change anything. I do not understand your comment Eliezer (except the sentence with the dollar sign).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch needs () after it like so:

`Logs.find({}, {sort:{date: -1}}).fetch();`

Comment: If you look at my picture you see that I am using () after fetch. I actually already fxied the problem by using an array instead of an object as sort option but I am not allowed to answer my own question at the moment